# How to export from a html form to a csv file using PHP

Tags: php, csv, post, fputcsv

Attempt #1:

```
$title = $_POST['title'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$description = $_POST['description'];
$type = $_POST['type'];
$content = $_POST['content2'];

$fs = fopen("blogPosts.csv", "a");
fputcsv($fs, array($title,$email,$description,$type,$content2,));
fclose($fs);
```

Attempt #2:

```
$title = $_POST['title'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$description = $_POST['description'];
$type = $_POST['type'];
$content = $_POST['content2'];

$list = array (
    array($title, $email, $description, $type, $content)
);
$fileName = "blogPosts.csv";

function generateCsv(array $list, $fileName,  $delimiter = ',', $enclosure = '"') {
    $handle = fopen($fileName, 'r+');
    foreach ($list as $line) {
        fputcsv($handle, $line, $delimiter, $enclosure);
    }
    rewind($handle);
    $contents = '';
    while (!feof($handle)) {
        $contents .= fread($handle, 8192);
    }
    fclose($handle);
    return $contents;
}

generateCsv($list, 'blogPosts.csv');
```

These are two attempts that I have had at appending to a csv file using PHP. The first one currently does not work. The second one writes to the second lines, but overwrites the first line deleting the previous record.

I need to insert the 5 variables into a new line every time.

Comment: For your second attempt you probably want `$handle = fopen($fileName, 'a+');` Then it should work. In your first attempt you define `$content` but later use `$content2`. The rest looks fine as well.

Comment: Yes the first one works now, thought it was going to be something stupid like that. Thank you!